# Contraction mapping theorem/Fixed point theorem application

Tags: real-analysis, fixed-point-theorems

The question is as follows:

> Use the contraction mapping theorem to show that the following system of equations:
>
> $x_1$ + $\dfrac{1}{10}\cos(2x_1 + x_2)$ = $1$
>
> $x_2$ + $\dfrac{1}{10}\sin(x_1 + x_2)$ = $2$.
>
> has a unique solution $(x_1, x_2)$ on $\mathbb{R^2}$.

I'm a *little* familiar with the contraction mapping theorem in terms of one variable, but this is a whole different beast....any push in the right direction is appreciated!

Comment: Let us try the obvious thing first. Define $x=(x_1,x_2)^T\in\mathbb{R}^2$, rearrange the given two equations gives $x=Tx$, where $T\colon\mathbb{R}^2\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ is the map defined by $Tx=(1-0.1\cos(2x_1+x_2), 2-0.1\sin(x_1+x_2))$. Now, you have to pick a metric on $\mathbb{R}^2$ and show that $T$ is a contraction. I don't know how this will end but try write out $d(Tx,Ty)$ and see what happens!

Answer (score 1):

Get $x_1$ and $x_2$ into their own equations and then find the Jacobian matrix. Then apply the $\infty$-norm to find $q$ which will be between zero and one, not inclusive.

Edit (by popular demand):

I wrote this on my phone whilst picking up dinner, so please do excuse my terse response.

Here is what I mean by getting $x_1$ and $x_2$ by themselves. You want \begin{align*}x_1&=\frac{1}{10}[1-x_2-\sin(x_1+x_2)]\\x_2&=\frac{1}{10}[2+x_1+\cos(x_1-x_2)]\end{align*} and then you will find the Jacobian matrix by taking partial derivatives with respect to $x_1$ and $x_2$. Then use the $\infty$-norm of the Jacobian to find what $q$ is.

Comment: Maybe you can show us how this looks? Not sure what you mean: "*Get x1
 and x2
 into their own equations*"

Comment: I made edits to my original response. I hope that this sheds some light on what I mean. I hope that the Jacobian part is pretty straightforward, but if not, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

The way to apply the contraction theorem is to write it in the form $f(\overrightarrow{X})=\overrightarrow{X}$ for $\overrightarrow{X}=(x_1, x_2).$ The form of the equations sort of gives away what $f$ should be; you then just need to show that it is a contraction. That is, show that $|f(\overrightarrow{X})-f(\overrightarrow{Y})|\leq c|\overrightarrow{X}-\overrightarrow{Y}|$ for all pairs of vectors, and for $c<1$. From there you get that $f$ has a unique fixed point, which is what you want.

Comment: So we have that $\overrightarrow{X}$ = $(x_1, x_2)$, and thus all coordinates are of the form $\overrightarrow{X}$ = $(1 - .1cos(2x_1 + x_2), 2 - .1sin(x_1 + x_2))$, no? I'm just a bit confused as to how we compare $\overrightarrow{X}$ and $\overrightarrow{Y}$ in this case....

Comment: Using the Pythagorean theorem: adding the squares of the difference of coordinates. But, you can also take the $2\times 2$ Jacobi matrix (differential of $f$: consisting of rows $\partial_1f,\ \partial_2f$) and show that its norm is always less than $1$.

Comment: @mizichael not exactly. What is $f$ in this case? And "comparing" is just done by subtracting, as in my answer.

Comment: @Berci I'm sorry if I'm being dense but I'm really not following...the contraction mapping theorem really confuses me because I never feel like I know for sure what, for example, $f(\overrightarrow{X})$ is in this case, or how I would even go about proving that |$f(\overrightarrow{X}) - f(\overrightarrow{Y})$| $\leq$ $c|\overrightarrow{X} - \overrightarrow{Y}|$....

Comment: @BobJones wait, is it such that $\overrightarrow{X}$ = $(x_1, x_2)$, and $f(\overrightarrow{x})$ = the corresponding values of $x_1$ and $x_2$, or $1 - .1cos(2x_1 + x_2)$ and $2 - .1sin(x_1 + x_2)$? I mean surely notationally this is incorrect, but is the premise that this function $f$ gives us $1 - .1cos(2x_1 + x_2)$ and $2 - .1sin(x_1 + x_2)$ when we plug in any $x_1$, $x_2$?

Comment: @mizichael If I tell you that $f(x_1, x_2)=(1-0.1\cos(2x_1+x_2), 2-0.1\sin(x_1+x_2))$, does that help? It is perfectly possible to have your output be a vector. Also, what is it that you want to prove, written out in terms of $x_1$ and $x_2$? It looks nicer than you might think.

Comment: @BobJones Okay, I think a big problem I've had is getting my head wrapped around the notion that the output could simply be a vector. We want to prove that there exists a unique $(x_1, x_2)$ which satisfies the series of equations, and we can prove this if we can prove there exists a $c$ such that the inequality mentioned earlier holds. Is this right?

Comment: @mizichael exactly. Can you continue?

Comment: @BobJones sorry, just had to think about that for a second. Okay, so we need to prove the inequality, and we have that $f(\overrightarrow{X})$ (where $\overrightarrow{X}$ = ($x_1, x_2$)) = $(1 - 0.1 cos(2x_1 + x_2), 2 - 0.1 sin(x_1 + x_2))$. How do we write out something like |$f(\overrightarrow{X}) - f(\overrightarrow{Y})$| then?

Comment: @BobJones Wait...would |$f(\overrightarrow{X}) - f(\overrightarrow{Y})$| = |$-0.2 cos(2x_1 + x_2)$, $-0.2 sin(x_1 + x_2)$|?

Comment: @mizichael Say $\overrightarrow{Y}=(y_1, y_2)$. Then what is $f(\overrightarrow{Y})$? From here, you should be able to subtract the vector outputs of $f$, right? Then the absolute value is just by Pythagorean theorem.

Comment: @BobJones then $f(\overrightarrow{Y})$ = $(1 - 0.1cos(2y_1 + y_2), 2 - 0.1 sin(y_1 + y_2))$. Hmm....I think I see. However, how do I apply the Pythagorean theorem here to move forward in the proof? I'm just a little confused about that. I think I have the notation down now, but the proof is eluding me (thank you so much for all of your help up to this point!)

Comment: @mizichael If we rewrite what you want to prove based on what we've discovered, we want to show $|(0.1\cos(2y_1+y_2)-0.1\cos(2x_1+x_2), 0.1\sin(y_1+y_2)-0.1\sin(x_1+x_2)|\leq|(x_1-y_1, x_2-y_2)|$. Do you agree? Now the question is what the absolute value of a vector is. There's many different possibilities, but the usual is that $|(a_1, a_2)|=\sqrt{a_1^2+a_2^2}$. This is where the Pythagorean Theorem comes in. And once you see this, this is where the real difficulty of the problem is. You have to show some weird inequality to do with $\sin$ and $\cos$.

Comment: @BobJones ah, I understand now. Luckily I'm fairly strong in algebraic manipulation - the whole premise of the problem was just baffling to me! But it seems fairly clear to me now. Thanks again for taking all this time to help me out - I really appreciate it.